# Using "background-position" but my background image is disappearing

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-position

I want to use a background image, but I'd like to adjust its position.  I'd like to move it up by -10 pixels.  I noticed that when I added a background position my image would disappear.  So I tried setting everything to zero, so nothing would move, like so

```
#pageTitle {
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url(http://hddfhm.com/images/clipart-110-scale-14.jpg)
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
```

but even then, my background image disappears -- https://jsfiddle.net/eq6zxpcb/5/ .  If I remove

```
background-position: 0px 0px;
```

the background image appears, but its not in the place taht I want.  How do I add a background position without making my image disappear?

Comment: you have no semi-colon after your `background-image` style, it seems like a syntax error. See updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eq6zxpcb/10/)

Comment: Roses are red, violets are blue, You are missing a ';' in line 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#pageTitle {
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url(http://hddfhm.com/images/clipart-110-scale-14.jpg);
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
```

after this `background-image: url(http://hddfhm.com/images/clipart-110-scale-14.jpg)` semicolon (;) was not there